# MySQL query to find top items

Tags: mysql

I have a table called order_list with the following fields

- order_id
- user_id
- item_id
- count
- date
- order_status

every time users place order, this table used to save order details. so how can I write my SQL query to find top 10 items based on the sum of ordered count?

Comment: I'd suggest you to have it precalculated in separated table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT item_id, SUM(count) FROM order_list GROUP BY item_id ORDER BY SUM(count) DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

Comment: Nested query in this case is not good idea - mysql cannot optimize such cases and you'll get N+1 queries

Comment: Remove `*` (this will make query ansi sql valid) and I'll upvote you ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name 
GROUP BY item_id 
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: You also need `GROUP BY` (and `SUM`)

Answer (score 0):

```
select item_id, sum(count) as total 
from order_list 
group by item_id 
order by total desc 
limit 10
```

Comment: i think this won't work, it'll say that total used in order by doesn't exist